# How to insert current user ID in a shortcode?

Tags: pages, shortcode, variables

I have a shortcode from a plug-in called Pods that is used like

```
[pods-form name="user" id="" fields="my_field, my_field_2, my_field_3"]
```

Parameter `name` contains the name of the custom post type (here: enhanced the WP user post type). Parameter `id` now shall receive the user ID of the currently logged in user. The page containing this shortcode is only available to logged-in users. How to add the current user ID as a variable to this shortcode?

I'm looking for something like this

```
[pods-form name="user" id="{@user_ID}" fields="my_field, my_field_2, my_field_3"]
```

Comment: You might use a custom string and filter it later, e.g `id=@__current_user_id` and `add_filter('the_content', function($c){ return str_replace( '@__current_user_id', get_current_user_id(), $c ); });` or look at [`shortcode_atts_pods-form`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/shortcode_atts_shortcode/) filter if the plugin uses `shortcode_atts()` to parse attributes.

Comment: In the [specification of the shortcode](http://pods.io/docs/learn/shortcodes/pods/) provided by the Pods plugin, there is a parameter _id_ already in existence. However, examples in the documentation only show static values for this parameter, whereas I want to insert the appropriate user's ID dynamically

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say how you were going to implement the code:  If you are using page templates or custom post pages, you could do this:

```
<?php

$user_id = get_current_user_id();
if ($user_id == 0) {
    echo 'You are currently not logged in.';
} else {
    echo do_shortcode('[pods-form name="user" id="'.$user_id.'" fields="my_field, my_field_2, my_field_3"]');
}
?>
```

are you looking to add this after your content or before on all pages you could add this to your functions.php

```
function 247070_before_after($content) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if ($user_id == 0) {
        $formstatement = 'You are currently not logged in.';
    } else {
        $formstatement = do_shortcode('[pods-form name="user" id="'.$user_id.'" fields="my_field, my_field_2, my_field_3"]');
    }

$addlcontent = $formstatement;
$fullcontent = $content . $addlcontent;  //move $addlcontent in front of $content to add your from to the front.
return $fullcontent;
}
add_filter('the_content', '247070_before_after');
```

Comment: Actually, I'm not implementing the shortcode code by myself. I'm using a ready-made shortcode that comes with the [Pods](https://www.pods.io) plugin. I want to use this shortcode in a WP page to output data of a custom post type created with Pods.

Comment: You can still use the code in this answer